# DXA: Context cookie not created and IsMobile is false

Tags: dxa

I am using DXA 1.1. problem i am facing context cookie is missing and isMobile is always false even when i access from mobile.

is this because of cookie, from where this cookie is set. i am using modified version not Out of box DXA.

Answer (score 3):

Is it only `IsMobile` that is not working, or are other context settings incorrect? You can check this, for example by debugging and checking the `WebRequestContext.ScreenWidth` - this should change, as you change your browser size and refresh the page.

If some claims are there, but others not, it may be that you have not set up SDL Mobile correctly (see [docs](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-8E5F4BCD-E975-43A1-9884-BDD73D232195)) and the site is only able to determine claims that work based on the Javascript (which sets the cookie).

If no claims are set, then it maybe that an error in Javascript (custom or DXA standard) is preventing the cookie being set - check your browser console for errors.